# Matrices Manipulations.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let A be a unitary matrix of rank $n$ , $AA^{*} = A^{*}A = I_n$

Let B be a self adjoint matrix of rank $n$, which means that $B^{*}=B$

Also $AB$ is normal, which means $AB(AB)^{*} = (AB)^{*}AB$

I want to prove that $AB^{2} = B^{2}A$

So

$AB^{2} = ABB = ABB^{*}AA^{*} = ABB^{*}A^{*}A = AB(AB)^{*}A = (AB)^{*}ABA = B^{*}A^{*}ABA = B^{*}BA = B^{2}A$

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct.

It might be slightly simpler to rewrite

$$AB(AB)^{*} = (AB)^{*}AB$$

As

$$AB^2A^*=ABB^*A^*=B^*A^*AB=B^2$$

Then multiply both sides by $A$.

But it's really equivalent to you approach.